# Barcode reader on website without https//

Tags: jquery, html, ssl

I'd like to build an web application where you can scan barcodes.
When i first found HTML5/Jquery plugins i was excited.
But as i´ve been reading for a while i notice that i cannot use the getUserMedia/Stream API without a SSL (https) certified website.

Maby i can use the HTML5 `input capture="camera"` and then "read" the img with some kind of Jquery plugin?

I find the `quaggaJS` interesting, but i think i cannot use the livestream without https.

Is there a way around of getting a https certificate?

Comment: You can get free certificate: https://www.startssl.com/

Comment: or https://letsencrypt.org

Comment: Interesting i will read up on those!